# Google Earth Engine task.id not showing correct id format?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

```
const task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage({
      //task description
  });

  task.start(() => {
    console.log("Task started: " + task.id)
  }, (error) => {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  });
```

When I run the above code, the task id that is logged to the console has the form of a uuid, e.g. `Task started: 45cb84eb-c9fc-4887-9016-91a4c9fdfacb`, whereas if I list the operations using `ee.data.listOperations()`, the taskid is in a completely different format e.g. `TLWZI4LX3SXU7LPMAVEZNMOG`.

When I use `ee.data.getOperation(task.id)`, I get an error message saying that there is no task with that id, but when I pass the id listed in the `ee.data.listOperations()` array, it works.

Is there any way to get the correct task id from the task object itself?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some weird mix of Javascript and Python in your syntax, but the ID with dashes is a temporary ID before the server has assigned a real one.  You have to call task.status() to get the real ID.

Comment: Could you explain what the weird mix is? What would I need to change to make this snippet more javascript-y? When I call task.status(), I get an error message saying that task.status is not a function (and task.status is undefined), could you explain where I am supposed to call task.status()?

Comment: The earth engine JS API uses ES5, so use anonymous functions instead of ES6 arrow functions would be less weird. I agree it's confusing. toCloudStorage() does not document a return type of task, and task.start() is not documented.  See also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/293777310.